# Stop Sublime Text from executing infinite loop

Tags: python, sublimetext3

When I do something like

```
while True:
    print('loop')
```

and execute that code in sublime I am not able to stop it. I have to manually kill the process and restart sublime.

Is there a way of setting some kind of `'max_execution_time'` or any other workaround which allow us to stop this nicely?

Comment: `Ctrl + C` should act as a keyboard interrupt.

Comment: unfortunately, this only works in terminal but not in sublime. Sublime gets kind of frozen and ignores all input.

Comment: yeah Ctrl C is listed as `stop  build` but does nothing ... I just use `pstree` in terminal to see what sublime is hung on and kill that child process :(

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You want to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>. For your own information, just go check under Tools in **Sublime Text** and you'll see *Cancel Build* and the above hotkey. It'll work just fine for infinite loops. Suffice to say, I've had the same happen! ;)

---

For Windows users, there is no <kbd>Break</kbd> key, so go into Preferences>Key Bindings and change the line

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+break"], "command": "cancel_build" }
```

to a different shortcut, such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>

Comment: Seems like that would be a solution. But as soon as an infinite loop starts, sublime (python) will eat all the cpu and ignores all input.

Comment: @Finn That's strange. I'd be curious to see what sort of code you're running. Now that I think of it, there was one time where the same happened to me, but I don't remember at the moment what it was that caused it. I'd be ***very*** interested in understanding more about what can cause Sublime to ignore all input. Surely, this `while True:
    print('loop')`  doesn't cause the problem you describe though, right? The same thing on my machine can easily be interrupted with the mentioned hotkey.

Comment: So finally i am able to use `ctrl + break` after i reinstalled sublime and python..

Comment: Would be nice if sublime had a default setting to break out automatically

Comment: @krozaine for me (in windows 7) this shortcut doesn't work. If so, you might want to open sublime key bindings ("Preferences" - "Key Bindings") and change the line `{ "keys": ["ctrl+break"], "command": "cancel_build" },` to something like `{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+b"], "command": "cancel_build" },`. Then the shortcut is CTRL + ALT + B

Answer (score 9):

For me (on Linux), there is no `break` key on the keyboard and this shortcut was somehow bound to a different combination: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

You can find where it is bound in the `Tools` menu:

[image]

After interrupting your script you should see the text `[Cancelled]` printed to the sublimetext console.

Comment: For me (on linux), there is no "Cancel build". It's listed in the menu, but it's grayed out, and there is no shortcut assigned. Just killed it again... The "break" key seems to be the third in the weird seldom used three-button block in the top row, right above 'delete'/'pos-1'/'up', but it does nothing.

Answer (score 4):

The combination is `ctrl+break`.

In Windows there is no break button, so you can go to `Preferences > Key Bindings` and to the user side add this:

`{ "keys" : ["ctrl+c"], "command": "cancel_build"}`

Now, by pressing Ctrl+C the execution will stop. Of course, you can change the combination to whatever you want.

**UPDATE**

As @Brad mentioned, Ctrl+C will override the copy keyboard shortcut. It is wise to assign another key to it, such as Q as Brad pointed out.

Comment: Great approach to set up everything up to your needs! Thanks.

Comment: This will override the copy keyboard shortcut. I set it to ctrl+q as I don't do any macro recording.

Comment: Thank you for the observation. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For MacOS:

```
cmd + option + esc
```

to force quit

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options here.
You could set a huge maximum number of iterations (I actually do this with most while loops until I've completely debugged my code, to avoid infinite loop pains):
So for example

```
max_iterations = 100000000
while i < max_iterations:
   print("Hello World")
```

An alternative would be using time module to clock the execution time of your code like this

```
import time
max_execution_time = 10000000 #this will be in seconds
start_time = time.clock()
elapsed_time = 0   
while elapsed_time < max_execution_time:
    elapsed_time = time.clock() = start_time
    #Your loop code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Just type **CTRL+C** key on *MacOS*.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow this in case you are using Sublime Text 3, go to Preferences > Package Settings > Alignment > Key Bindings-User

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+n"], "command": "cancel_build" }
]
```

Now, by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>, the execution will immediately stop. Of course, you can change the combination to whatever you want (In place of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>).

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember why exactly, but for me `cancel_build` sometimes doesn't work.

Instead I'm using this and it works all the time:

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+b"], "command": "exec", "args": {"kill": true} }
]
```