# NodeJS EADDRINUSE Sublime Text 3

Tags: node.js, port, sublimetext3

I created a new build system for Node following this: http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Javascript-Console-in-Sublime-Text

I can run it once (I run it with Control+B) but I can only run it once. Second time I run it I get this error:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1042:14)
    at listen (net.js:1064:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1138:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/Documents/Projects/testnode.js:13:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

I have read other posts, I can't "Cancel Build". I have read I can kill the process, I can use a different port each time I run it but that's not smooth.

I want something like `reuseaddr` in `socat`, be able to modify the server and rerun it again wihout having to wait the linger time for the TCP connection to dissapear.

How should I proceed? Thank you in advance

Comment: Usually you can stop a script with `ctrl+c` on osx. I think it's the same for windows but not sure.

Comment: `ctrl+c` copies on the Sublime Text console

Comment: what about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28397473/stop-sublime-text-from-executing-infinite-loop)?

Comment: I have the `Cancel Build` option blocked (in grey)

Comment: I have tried installing nodemon, and building the code with it but not success......

Comment: My solution has been adding this line on the `Preferences > Key Bindings > User` ->  `{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+k"], "command": "exec", "args": {"kill": true} }
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>break</kbd> to kill the process